Shadcn/radix asChild throws `React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.`
<SelectTrigger asChild>
    <Button
        variant="outline"
        role="combobox"
        className={cn(
            "w-[200px] justify-between",
            !field.value &&
                "text-muted-foreground",
        )}
    >
        <>
            {field.value
                ? getAllFormFactors.data?.find(
                        (formFactor) =>
                            formFactor.id === field.value,
                    )?.name
                : "Select form factor"}
            <ChevronsUpDown className="ml-2 h-4 w-4 shrink-0 opacity-50" />
        </>
    </Button>
</SelectTrigger>

I tried replacing the button with a simple div, the error still throws, the error is gone once I remove asChild
